# Docker behind a proxy requires restart on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, docker

I apologise if I am posting this in the wrong section, I need some help and unsure where to turn to.

I am trying to run docker behind a proxy on a linux/ubuntu server machine. I have configured every proxy on the box (FTP/HTTPS/HTTP), I have also configured the Docker proxies mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093517/4261713

However, I have the docker service set to auto-start on machine boot, unless I log onto the machine and run `sudo service docker restart` those settings are ignored, and docker fails to use a proxy. This is all fine, we have a work around for local access, but I need to use this machine remotely using auto-builds/deployments etc. Therefore, the builds break without running that command.

Unfortunately I cannot get any help from Docker support, I have waited around 3 weeks for them to reply with no luck. This problem is more than likely me not understanding linux services/daemons. Can someone help me out?

To confirm what I have already tried:

1. I have created the http-proxy.conf in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and created the Environment variable there for the proxy.
2. I have tried to modify the docker service init.d file by adding to the `"DOCKER_OPTS"` variable at the top using `-e "HTTP_PROXY=http://addressofproxy:portofproxy" -e "HTTPS_PROXY=http://addressofproxy:portofproxy"` However, this also has made no difference and I still need to restart the service after a reboot!
3. I have also set/configured the client config in `~/.docker/config.json` to have the proxies in.

Any assistance is much appreciated, I am totally stuck with why it wont read the options in on startup.

Answer (score 0):

On OS running systemd you could try to add: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`

with content:

`[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:3128/" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy:3128/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1"`

then

`systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker`